# php character match and allow special characters

Tags: php, database, authentication, web

I am trying to make a **website** which will use `registration, login actions`.

I am trying it in my **localhost**. 
At this stage I've created only database for users and login action.

The **problem** is I've set my username "viral4ever" in database. Login action is working properly but I can login using "viral4ever", "VIRAL4EVER" and all. I don't want that in my system. I want to **check every character** in my database to login, if it matches "viral4ever" then it should get me in, not with Viral4ever or vIRAL4ever or VIRAL4EVER and all.

I also want to allow users to use **".", "_","-"** in their username. So kindly help me with this.

I am using MySQL database and to login and check users I am using this function...

```
function user_exists($username){
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}


function sanitize($data) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}
```

Comment: please post the code that implements the authentication, otherwise your request has no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new mysql table, you can choose between different character sets. Many have "_ci" in their name, which means "case insensitive".

Looks like you need to choose a case sensitive one.

Comment: It helped me a lot and working. I changed username into UTF8_bin. Is it perfect to use? Now I need to allow . and - and _ in username. I've already created a username viral.joshi but I cant login with this username.